# Как сделать двойной ховер(в данном случае)?

Tags: html, css, sass

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.circle-icon-1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 3px solid transparent;
  transition: .2s ease-out;
  position: relative; }

.circle-icon-1 a {
  width: 35px;
  height: 57px;
  display: block;
  background: url(/img/icon-phone.png) no-repeat;
  transition: .2s linear;
  position: absolute; }

.circle-icon-1:hover a {
  background: url(/img/icon-phone-effect.png) no-repeat; }

.circle-icon-1:hover {
  border: 3px solid #fac81b; }
  
//Один из способов реализации перепробованый мной...Но увы это криво(((
//Писал на Sass потому свойства не сокращены
```

```html
<div class="circle-icon-1">
  <a href="#"></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Почему бы не использовать просто тег **a** класса `.circle-icon-1`? Посмотрите следующий вариант:

```css
.circle-icon-1 {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: url(/img/icon-phone.png) no-repeat center center;
  background-size: 50%; /* Подгоняете размер background'а */
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 200px;
  border: 3px solid transparent;
  transition: .2s ease-out;
}

.circle-icon-1:hover {
  border: 3px solid #fac81b;
  background: url(/img/icon-phone-effect.png) no-repeat center center;
}
```

```html
<a class="circle-icon-1" href="#"></a>
```

Comment: Так не выйдет ибо в таком случае один background будет загораживать другой...Должен быть контейнер для иконки.

Comment: @L1ght_time, разве при :hover в данном случае не происходит замена изображения?